# How to solve this integral: $\int \frac{\sqrt{-x^2 - x + 2}}{x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Question is self explanatory. I have an exam and our professor gave us questions. This is the one I couldn't do. Any ideas would be very helpful:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{-x^2 - x + 2}}{x^2}dx$$

Comment: Ugh, I think this is a bit overcomplicated for an exam. Anyways, it might be a good start to integrate by parts (integrate $1/x^2$).

Comment: $-x^2-x+2=\frac94-\left(x+\frac 12\right)^2$

Comment: We learned partial integration, substitution of variables, integration of trigonometric functions and integration of irrational functions.

Comment: Looking at Wolfram's solution, it looks like you want to start with integration by parts, with the piece being integrated being $1/x^2$. Then (matching up with abiessu's suggestion) take $u=x+1/2$, hence $x=u-1/2$, and work from there. It looks like you use partial fractions at that stage, in the process getting a log and an inverse sine function. That...does sound rather horrifying for an exam, I certainly never had anything this hard on a calculus exam.

Comment: Hint: Integrate by parts, then complete the square in the integrand of the resulting integral, and then make an approrpiate trig substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: set $$\sqrt{-x^2-x+2}=xt+\sqrt{2}$$
we get $$x=\frac{-2t\sqrt{2}-1}{t^2+1}$$ and $$dx=\frac{2(-\sqrt{2}+t+\sqrt{2}t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? I tried what you suggest but I arrived to a monster which, to me, looks worse than the original integrand. Thanks.

Comment: This reads like the suggestion of a CAS gone mad. (And CAS do not answer query in comments either.)

Comment: this is the so called Euler substitution